# Titanium window orientation in navigation window of iphone

Tags: orientation

i want to change the orientation mode of perticular window on navigation window in ios titanium ?
Is there any way to change one window on slider in landscape mode and the the other navigation window same in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Setting specific [Orientation Modes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-orientationModes) should do the trick. Unless what you mean is a tab group/scrollable views with different orientations. That's might not behave as well as you like.

Comment: My Question is that ,Is it possible to change the orientation mode of navigation window in titanium ?  Or is there any other way to handle orientation on perticular navigation window ?